# How to parse にためになる

Tags: meaning, parsing

How can I parse this sentence:

> 外観よりも実際にためになることのほうがいい。

So that it means:

> In comparison to appearance, reality is better

Edit:
The complete paragraph is:

> 「花より団子」
>   お花見に行って、桜の花を見るより、そこで食べるおいしいだんごのほうがいい、外観よりも実際にためになることのほうがいい。

Where「花より団子」is a proverb being defined

Comment: Maybe 実際に as in ", actually," (with pauses) and ためになる as in "to be useful" (in reality; in contrast to outward appearance)

Comment: Or actually you don't need the pauses for that "actually" to make sense. It can just strengthen being useful.

Comment: @jon Are you sure that translation is correct?

Comment: @user3856370 Its not an exact translation, it's to give a general idea. It's making a comparison  between two things and stating that people prefer one rather than the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「外観{がいかん}よりも実際{じっさい}にためになることのほうがいい。」

From your question title "How to parse にためになる", it is clear that you are already parsing the middle part of the phrase incorrectly.

It is 「実際に + ためになる」. ⇒ ("beneficial in a practical sense")

It is not 「実際 + にためになる」. ⇒ Makes little sense.

The phrase in question is making a comparison between two things:

1) 「外観」⇒ "the appearnace" ⇒ ***flower viewing***

2) 「実際にためになること」⇒ "the beneficial thing in a practical sense" ⇒ ***eating dango***

and **it is saying that 2) is better than 1)**.

Thus, this sums up the meaning of the well-known saying 「花{はな}より団子{だんご}」.

「ためになる」 should be remembered as it is used ***very*** often.  It basically means "good-fo-ya".

Comment: So the に in 実際に means something like "sense" or "in a sense"?

Comment: No, of course not.  That is just a translation to make it sound good in the target language (English).  に enables 実際 to function adverbially so that 実際に can modify the verb phrase ためになる.   ～～に functions adverbially and ～～の functions adjectivally.

Answer (score 0):

> 外観よりも(実際に)ためになることのほうがいい

This is how I would parse it:

> 外観よりも in comparison to appearance
>   実際に in reality/for practical purposes
>   ためになることのほうが act of being useful side
>   いい is good

Or in other words:

> In reality, being useful is better than apperance.
>   In practice, It's better to be useful than to look good.

Which is not quite the same as your TL.